# Запятая в обороте "только тот, кто" после изъятия части "тот"

Tags: пунктуация

*Я открываю только тому, кому хочу.
Она говорит только с тем, с кем считает нужным.
Я делаю только то, что должен.*

Если в подобных приложениях изъять слово "тот" (в разных его видах), то что будет с запятой? Она удалится, останется на месте или переедет в положение перед "только"?

*Я открываю только кому хочу.
Она говорит только с кем считает нужным.
Я делаю только что должен.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для решения задачи надо определить **тип предложения**.  Это сложноподчиненные предложения (СПП) с местоименной связью  определенного вида, а именно  **местоименно-определительные СПП.**  В них местоименную пару образует указательное слово (коррелят) и союзное слово: тому – кому, с тем – с кем, то – что.
2. В общем случае (в правильной литературной речи) наличие указательного слова в предложениях этого вида **обязательно**, а вы **собираетесь его изъять.**
3. **Допустимо ли это?** В принципе  да, но при этом мы получаем разговорную речь и стилистически сниженную конструкцию. Частица «только» будет относиться к союзному слову, запятая останется:

*Я открываю, **только кому хочу.** Она говорит, **только с кем считает нужным.** Я делаю,  **только что должен**.*

3. **А когда недопустимо?** Убрать коррелят нельзя, если падежи  местоимений не совпадают, например:

*Я занимаюсь только **тем, что** мне интересно.* Нельзя сказать: *Я занимаюсь, только что мне интересно.*

4. **А запятая всегда ставится**?  Запятой не будет, если придаточное предложение заменить устойчивым оборотом, например:  *Я открываю **кому хочу.**  Она говорит **с кем ей нужно.** Я делаю **что должен**.*

В этом случае оборот максимально упрощен и по смыслу соответствует одному слову, например: Я открываю не всем.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! Да, реплики подразумевались именно как разговорные.
Коррелят -- новое для меня понятие, изучу его подробнее.

Comment: Пожалуйста,  успехов вам  в изучении русского языка. Коррелят (от лат. correlatio – соотношение), СООТНОСИТЕЛЬНОЕ слово. В школьной практике его называют УКАЗАТЕЛЬНЫМ словом. А указывает он на то местоимение (то, так, такой), содержание которого раскрывает придаточное предложение. Интересно, что в схемах различных предложений он изображается так:  +к, -к, ±к, то есть обязателен, невозможен, факультативен.